# How to Set parameters from child Job To parent Multi-Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have the Multi Job Project in Jenkins that contains several child multi job. Something like this:

```
ParentMultiJob{
 - childJobOne
 - childJobTwo
 - childJobThree
}
```

all they have String parameter: '**schema**'. so I run Parent Multi job with parameter **schema**='default' and the child jobs will have the same value of parameter **schema**('default').
**!!!But the childJobOne write new value of parameter schema in property file.** Also this value printed in console. And I need to get this value and set to next childJobs if the first job is green. 
For example:
1.

```
ParentMultiJob (parameter schema=default){
 - childJobOne (parameter schema=default, create property file where schema=custom, status = green)
 - childJobTwo (parameter schema=custom)
 - childJobThree (parameter schema=custom)
}
```

2.

```
ParentMultiJob (parameter schema=default){
 - childJobOne (parameter schema=default, create property file where schema=custom, status = false)
 - childJobTwo (parameter schema=default)
 - childJobThree (parameter schema=default)
}
```

How can I do it using groovy script or something else?